# problem displaying hebrew (right to left) last character on text fields

Tags: fields, text, rtl

We use Hebrew characters in our Salesforce org.

Whenever there is a symbol character (!,. etc) as the last character of the line, it displays as the first character:

[image]

You can see at this picture that I wrote `שלום` and added `!` at the end, but it displays the `!` at the start like this: `שלום!`

This behavior is the same for all text field, picklists etc.

Also it looks the same in lightning and in classic

**QUESTION**

Is this a bug?

Is there a way to display that correctly?